# getting Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

While running this app whenever I type any charater in searchbox getting error like cannot set param is undefined with popup message and when I close this popup error I am getting proper result.Can anyone please help me what I did wrong in my code,Below is my code.

**searchContactDetails.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="searchContactController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">   
       
    <!-- CREATE ATTRIBUTE/VARIABLE-->
    <aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
    <aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>
    
    <!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />
    
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
       <!-- SEARCH INPUT AND SEARCH BUTTON--> 
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                                 required="true"
                                 onkeyup="{!c.Search}"
                                 placeholder="search Contacts.."
                                 aura:id="searchField"
                                 updateOn="keyup" 
                                 label="Search"/><br/>
           <!-- </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">-->
                <!--<lightning:button onclick="{!c.Search}"
                                  variant="brand"
                                  label="Search"
                                  iconName="utility:search"/>-->
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
       
        <!-- TOTAL RECORDS BADGES--> 
        <div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
            Total Number Of Record:
            <lightning:badge label="{!v.TotalNumberOfRecord}" />
        </div>
        
        <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
            <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
                <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                    <div class="slds-notify__content">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
       
        <!-- TABLE CONTENT-->
        <div class="{!if(v.TotalNumberOfRecord != 0,'slds-show','slds-hide')}">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="S.no">S.no</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">First Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Last Name">Last Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Mobile">Phone</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="MailingCountry">Country</div>
                    </th>
                    
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <!--<th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="MailingCountry">Country</div>
                    </th>-->
                   
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <!--### display all records of searchResult attribute by aura:iteration ###-->
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="cont" indexVar="count">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!count + 1}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!cont.FirstName}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!cont.LastName}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!cont.MobilePhone}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!cont.MailingCountry}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!cont.Account.Name}</div>
                        </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**searchContactDetailsController.js**

```
({
    Search: function(component, event, helper) {
        var searchField = component.find('searchField');
        
        var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        // if value is missing show error message and focus on field
        if(isValueMissing) {
            searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            searchField.focus();
        }else{
          // else call helper function 
            helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
        }
    },
})
```

**searchContactDetailsHelper.js**

```
({
    SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
               var result = component.get("v.searchKeyword");
              if(result.length < 3)
              {
                  this.changeButtonLabel(component, event);
                  //console.log("Size of newGroupStructures = " + result.length);
                  //alert("Please Enter atleast three character to perform search");
              }
        else
        {
        
        // show spinner message
         component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
        var action = component.get("c.fetchContact");
        
        action.setParams({
            
            
            'searchKeyWord': component.get("v.searchKeyword")
        
        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           // hide spinner when response coming from server 
            component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                
                // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
                if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                    component.set("v.Message", true);
                } else {
                    component.set("v.Message", false);
                }
                
                // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
                component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);
                
                // set searchResult list with return value from server.
                component.set("v.searchResult", storeResponse); 
                
            }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert('Response is Incompleted');
            }else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        alert("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    },
    changeButtonLabel : function(component, event)
    {
        //alert('hi');
         var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title : 'Error',
            message:'Please Enter atleast 3 charater',
            duration:' 5000',
            key: 'info_alt',
            type: 'error',
            mode: 'pester'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

**searchContactController.apex**

```
public with sharing class searchContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
 public static List < contact > fetchContact(String searchKeyWord) {
  String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
  List < Contact > returnList = new List < Contact > ();
  List < Contact > lstOfContact = [select FirstName,LastName, MobilePhone,MailingCountry, Account.Name from contact
                                   where FirstName LIKE: searchKey or LastName LIKE: searchKey or Account.Name LIKE: searchKey  LIMIT 10];
 
  for (Contact acc: lstOfContact) {
   returnList.add(acc);
  }
  return returnList;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`force:showToast` is not valid in a Lightning App or Lightning Out. You can only use it in the Lightning Experience. Therefore:

```
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
```

Returns undefined, so the next line:

```
toastEvent.setParams({ ...
```

Throws the exception.

The typical way to handle this is to check if the action exists first, and if not, use an alternative method:

```
if(toastEvent) {
  toastEvent.setParams({ ... })
  toastEvent.fire();
} else {
  alert('Please Enter at least 3 characters!');
}
```